# How do you select just the row key in Hypertable's hql?

Tags: hypertable

I have a table in hypertable where the row key is a user id. I wanted to select just the row key itself, but I get parse errors for:

```
select ROW from users where ROW='1000' limit 5;
Error: Hypertable::Exception: Table= twitter/users , Column family=row - RANGE SERVER invalid column family
```

Is it possible to just get the row key using hql?

Answer (score 3):

USE KEYS_ONLY OPTION:

```
select * from users where ROW='1000' KEYS_ONLY limit 5;
```